# Netflix Archaius with Spring Cloud Config server

Tags: spring, spring-cloud, spring-cloud-netflix, spring-cloud-config

I followed [this](https://github.com/Netflix/archaius/wiki) documentation for Archaius and some other online articles. However, *presumably*, each service should have Archaius or configuration related codes/dependencies(-jars) to load configuration values. My concern is that if a change is required in loading configuration, then each service has to be reloaded/redeployed.
**Q1.** Can anyone let me know how to keep a centralized Archaius configuration service so that client services pull configurations.

On the contrary, Spring Cloud Config server does that job - all configurations are in one place. But I feel that it lacks loading configurations from a custom resource - data loads from a database as Archaius provides, for example.
**Q2**. Is there a work around  to make Config Server loads configurations from Archaius ?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

For **Q1**, you should look at the 2.x branch of Archaius, specifically https://github.com/Netflix/archaius/blob/2.x/archaius2-persisted2/src/main/java/com/netflix/archaius/persisted2/Persisted2ConfigProvider.java. This is configured to make a rest call to some service which will front your Config. At Netflix, we have a rest service backed by Cassandra. Naturally, you can back that with whatever you would like. But fair warning, this Archaius setup was made for Guice and requires a bit of manual setup. It is not quite as seamless as you might expect if you've been working with Spring Boot/Cloud starters for example.

For **Q2**, Spring Cloud Config does indeed support [loading data from a DB](http://cloud.spring.io/spring-cloud-static/spring-cloud-config/1.4.0.RELEASE/single/spring-cloud-config.html#_jdbc_backend). Also, in my experience with the Spring products, they are almost always quite easy to extend to your own purposes if you'd like to do something more custom.

General suggestion: If you have no other need/use of Archaius aside from remote config and you are a Spring user, I'd suggest just going with Spring Cloud. It would be far easier to configure and probably serve your requirements just fine.

Archaius provides a way to deal with reading dynamically changing Config with minimal performance impact. If you're not in Spring, or happen to need fast access to dynamic properties, consider Archaius.